# Pick 2 options out of 10 in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a question where the user has to pick 2 options out of 10 available options. How can I limit it to 2 and nothing more?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Although we do not have a setting that will let you do this. You can use a calculation field just below your Choice field to calculate how many items have been selected and show an error if two many options are picked.

You will need to start with your Choice field which I have titled 'Choices' and set to Checkboxes. You then need to add a Calculation field that I have titled 'Number of Choices' make sure you change the 'Type' of your Calculation field to 'Number'.

[image]

You can then use the following calculation to check the number of items that a user has selected in the referenced Choice field.

```
=Choices.Count()
```

The last step would be to assign a minimum and a maximum value to your Calculation field. This will show an error when to few choices have been selected and an error when to many choices have been selected. I have set mine to require at least 1 item and have a max of two items, this will let the user select only 1 or at most 2 from the choice list.

[image]

You can then see that I get an error when I try to make select more then 2 items and the form wont submit until this is corrected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can now add custom validation to any field or section in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  You can conditionally show error messages based on custom criteria, such as `=Choices.Count() < 1 or Choices.Count() > 2`.

[image]

Please review our help documentation for more details:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/11/building-forms/advanced-validation#custom-errors